# BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast not received even after manually started app

Tags: android, broadcast

I want to make an application start when the device booted, but it doesn't work, even after I added permission, intent-filters and category.

**I know that after android 3.1, app cannot be started by broadcast before user manually start it.**

So I ran app several times after installing it, but it still doesn't work.

Below is my code.

manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
...
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

and broadcast receiver class.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = "action : " + intent.getAction();
    Log.d("MyTag", action);
    Toast.makeText(context, action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
}
}
```

Comment: Try having separate receivers for each intent filter, sometimes manifest merger causes issues causing the receiver to not work. I faced a similar issue as yours and mine worked with this trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this tends to happen due to manifest merger issues.

Put the two intent filters in tell separate receivers and your code should work again. Let us know if it still doesn't work :)

Comment: I wrote a comment saying it was working, but it was probably deleted.

Comment: Welcome man :) accept the answer so that others don't keep checking this thread